# dynamic search using stored procedure asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a problem when implementing a dynamic search using stored procedures in asp.net 
i have a data table and database for time attendance system i want to search for an employee with main controls like his ID and Date, Device Type ...etc 
this is my Default.aspx.cs code

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    static string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            this.gridData();
            this.search();
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------
    private void gridData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EventUserId, EventDate, EventTime, Eventtype, Readerid FROM V_EventLogs"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private DataTable search()
    {
        DataTable sdt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("userSearch", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventUserId", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDateFrm", ASPxDateEdit1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDateTo", ASPxDateEdit2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Readerid", txtReader.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            // passs parameter to data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            sda.Fill(sdt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)            {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }

        return sdt;
    }



   //---------------------------------------------------


    protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.gridData();
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        GridView1.DataSource = search();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

}

And this is my Default.aspx Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>BioWeb TimeTel</h1>
    <p class="lead">Time Attendance</p>
    <%--<p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>--%>
</div>
<div>

        User ID:
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        Event Date:
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="ASPxDateEdit1" runat="server" DisplayFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy" EditFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy">
        </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
        <br />
        Event Time:
        <br />
        &nbsp;<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="ASPxDateEdit2" runat="server" DisplayFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy" EditFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy">
        </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
        &nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        Reader:
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtReader" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        &nbsp
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" OnLoad="Page_Load" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
        OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" UseAccessibleHeader="True" CssClass="table table-hover">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventUserId" HeaderText="User ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDate" HeaderText="Date IN" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventTime" HeaderText="Time IN" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Eventtype" HeaderText="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Readerid" HeaderText="Reader" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>     
    </div>
```

and my stored procedurs is :

```
CREATE procedure userSearch
(
@EventUserId int = NULL,
@EventDateFrm nvarchar(10) = NULL,
@EventDateTo nvarchar(10) = NULL,
@Readerid int = NULL
)
as
select V_EventLogs.EventUserId,V_EventLogs.EventDate,V_EventLogs.EventTime,V_EventLogs.Eventtype,V_EventLogs.Readerid 
from V_EventLogs 
where
(@EventUserId is NULL OR EventUserId = @EventUserId )
AND
(@EventDateFrm is NULL OR Convert(varchar(10),EventDate,110) >= Convert(varchar(10),@EventDateFrm,110))
AND 
(@EventDateTo is NULL OR Convert(varchar(10),EventDate,110)  <= Convert(varchar(10),@EventDateTo,110))
AND
(@Readerid is NULL OR Readerid = @Readerid)
```

now when i want to search for an employee the grid data table still empty and didn't get any values but when testing my stored procedure on SQL server working good 
- and the second problem is when paging the data table dynamic search working only for the first page when i choose any other page the search implementation does not work and data table showing all database values!! why ??

Comment: why don't you declare the Datatable out side of the method and do the binding after you return the data from the `gridData()` method change the signature to return a datatable also in the Page_Load have an else and bind the data there to the datagrid as well.. should be a simple fix.. also can you confirm when debugging if the data is actually being loaded in the datatable when calling the `Fill` method

Comment: also your paging should be the following 
`GridView1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;` then assign the datasource and databind like this 
`GridView1.DataSource = sdt;` //move the datatable instance outside the method make it public or static 
`GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: are you familiar with PostBacks..? but a breakpoint in your Page_Load event and you will see where you are going wrong.. you need an `if (IsPostBack) else { }` you do not need to check for == false either do `if(!IsPostBack){} else{}` or do `if(IsPostBack){} else{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question. You don't have any search happening in PageIndexChanging...

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.gridData();
}
```

The above code just simply re-binds the whole data as your gridData() method retrieves all records and setting NewPageIndex will simply move you to that page.

Try writing something like below:

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = search();
    }
```

This is not a perfect solution.  One should use Paging implemented in Stored Procedure itself; this SP should take page index and no of records per page as input along with other search criteria; You need to build a dynamic SQL to fetch corresponding page results within SP and bind it back to the Grid.  A simple Google search might give you alternate solutions.  But, the above change should work as your desired.

Comment: This also doesn't work the data grid not appear or show any search results but Stored Procedure working fine in Sql Server

Comment: As long as you don't understand and implement proper Paging concept, it is hard to explain here; There are plenty of articles out there on Internet; I would suggest you to understand the concepts of backend paging before implementation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to close connection only after Fill command, and don't call ExecuteNonQuery, like this:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("userSearch", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventUserId", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDateFrm", ASPxDateEdit1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDateTo", ASPxDateEdit2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Readerid", txtReader.Text);

    // passs parameter to data adapter
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    con.Open();
    sda.Fill(sdt);
    con.Close();
```

This if you wish to use DataAdapter. Otherwise, you can retrieve data directly:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("userSearch", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventUserId", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDateFrm", ASPxDateEdit1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDateTo", ASPxDateEdit2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Readerid", txtReader.Text);

    con.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var dtbl = new DataTable();
    dtbl.Load(reader);
    con.Close();
```

of course it would be better to put all into a try-catch and use "using" ..... :-)

Comment: i tried your code but didn't work the same error the data table does not got any data and i'm already using try catch but no exceptions

Comment: Your search function is called only on btnSearch_Click event handler.
have you tried debug and run the SP directly with the same parameters?

Comment: Yes i have tried SP on Sql Server and it's working but when i call it doesn't got any search values from SP and the data grid not appear

Answer (score 0):

You can Create dynamic search  SQL server stored procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE CUSTOMER.GET_DynamicSearch
(
    -- Optional Filters for Dynamic Search
    @CustomerID            INT = NULL,
    @CustomerName          NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @CustomerTitle         NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @locationId            int = NULL,
    @ControlCardNumber     bigint = NULL,
    @Formnumber            int = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE
    @lCustomerID            INT = NULL,
    @lCustomerName          NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @lCustomerTitle         NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @llocationId            int = NULL,
    @lControlCardNumber     bigint = NULL,
    @lFormnumber            int = NULL

    SET @lCustomerID          = @CustomerID
    SET @lCustomerName         = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CustomerName))
    SET @lCustomerTitle          = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CustomerTitle))
    SET @llocationId           = LTRIM(RTRIM(@locationId))
    SET @lControlCardNumber    = @ControlCardNumber
    SET @lFormnumber             = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Formnumber))

    SELECT
        c.CustomerId,
        c.CustomerName,
        c.CustomerTitle,
        c.LocationId,
        c.ControlCardNumber,
        c.FormNumber
    FROM CUSTOMER.Customer c
    WHERE
        (@lCustomerID IS NULL OR CustomerId = @lCustomerID)
    AND (@lCustomerName IS NULL OR CustomerName LIKE  '%' +@lCustomerName + '%')
    AND (@lCustomerTitle IS NULL OR CustomerTitle LIKE '%' + @lCustomerTitle + '%')
    AND (@llocationId IS NULL OR locationId = @llocationId )
    AND (@lControlCardNumber IS NULL OR ControlCardNumber = @lControlCardNumber)
    AND (@lFormnumber IS NULL OR Formnumber = @lFormnumber)
    ORDER BY c.CustomerID asc

END
GO
```

Execution Details

```
EXEC CUSTOMER.GET_DynamicSearch -- 2000  records
```

-- On providing only CustomerName parameter:

```
EXEC CUSTOMER.GET_DynamicSearch @CustomerName= 'Uttam' -- 1040 records
```